# Why pipes are not deleted using "gsub" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, heredoc, gsub

I would like to delete from `notes` everything starting from the `example_header`. I tried to do:

```
example_header = <<-EXAMPLE
    -----------------
    ---| Example |---
    -----------------
EXAMPLE

notes = <<-HTML
    Hello World
    #{example_header}
    Example Here
HTML

puts notes.gsub(Regexp.new(example_header + ".*", Regexp::MULTILINE), "")
```

but the output is:

```
    Hello World
    ||
```

Why `||` isn't deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pipes in your regular expression are being interpreted as the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Your regular expression will replace the following three strings:

```
"-----------------\n---"
" Example "
"---\n-----------------"
```

You can solve your problem by using [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) to escape the string when you use it in a regular expression ([ideone](http://ideone.com/t5KVY)):

```
puts notes.gsub(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(example_header) + ".*",
                           Regexp::MULTILINE),
                "")
```

You could also consider avoiding regular expressions and just using the ordinary string methods instead ([ideone](http://ideone.com/RoE8e)):

```
puts notes[0, notes.index(example_header)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest a method to achieve the same without regular expressions?

Comment: @Phrogz: That won't work because Misha wants to delete the header *and everything after it*.

Answer (score 3):

Pipes are part of regexp syntax (they mean "or"). You need to escape them with a backslash in order to have them count as actual characters to be matched.